# さあていくわ vs さあ行くわ

Tags: grammar, word-choice, nuances, phrases

> Eat Mom's Breakfast
>
> Toast, Jams, Milk of おいしい牛乳
>
> さあて行くわあたし happy happy girl!

From the intro of a song (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KS2t7l89Lm0)

The English words are being sung in English.

I understand everything in the bolded sentence except the use of 〜て行く(or maybe it's some other construction I haven't recognised?)

Exactly why is the て there? The sentence would make sense if it was just さあ行くわ.

Answer (score 4):

[さて](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/88595/meaning/m0u/) (> さあて) and [さあ](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/84286/meaning/m0u/) are separate interjections. Both can have several possible English renderings that might be rather confusing, but さて is uttered when you shift the focus of interest to another topic, and さあ is a word to spur someone to take a (dynamic) action.

In your context both can be filled in, but they tell different things. If I had to make some (shoddy) translation:

> さあて行くわ *And now, I gotta go!*
>   さあ行くわ *Here goes!*

Answer (score 2):

さて・さーて is own expression meaning roughly 'right then' (as in 'Right then, I'll be going').

Meanwhile, さあ invites someone to do something. So さあて行くわ is 'Right then, I'm going', whereas さあ行くわ is 'Come on, let's go'.

Comment: Explanation for the downvote?